# How can I configure TeraCopy so that it retries copying a file in case of a CRC mismatch?

Tags: windows, file-transfer, teracopy

How can I configure TeraCopy so that it retries copying a file in case of a CRC mismatch?

[image]

Comment: You can't. I tried.

Comment: @FleetCommand Thanks feel free to convert your comment as an answer.

Comment: Nah. I don't want to glorify my reply. The answer section is reserved for solving someone's problem. I didn't solve yours.

Comment: @FleetCommand The issue is that questions with 0 answer and a score of 0 are automatically deleted after a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cannot configure TeraCopy so that it retries copying a file in case of a CRC mismatch. However retrying all failed copies can be done at once via the TeraCopy GUI:

1. Click on Skipped:

   [image]
2. Select all failed copies and click on `Copy`:

   [image]
3. Done:

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is not specifically for CRC errors and retries, but.. For anyone still wondering, what helps for me when TeraCopy fails on any error, is closing TeraCopy and then restarting it. There will be an option to resume the current list. The version of TeraCopy I'm using at this moment is version 3.1.

Hope this helps.